# Error: The getter 'completercd' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, pub.dev

I'm currently following FreeCodeCamp's tutorial on Youtube on how to make a Flutter Instagram clone, and I'm getting this error when I try to compile my code to run on Chrome.

These are my dependencies:

```
cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase_auth: ^4.2.5
firebase_core: ^2.4.1
firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
```

After some more testing, it seems that updating firebase_core to version 2.0.0 is what is causing this error. However, my other dependencies depend on firebase_core 2.0.0, so going backwards isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I switched my IDE from VSCode to IntelliJ IDEA, my issue with the firebase packages was fixed. When I tried running it on VSCode again, I didn't didn't experience this problem again. I checked the pubspec.yaml files and they look the same.